# BigQuery ga_realtime_sessions table lifecycle

Tags: google-bigquery

I was wondering when does Google BigQuery drop the `ga_realtime_sessions` table for the previous day, I know it's not midnight UTC time, is there a definitive time that such action happens?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean ga__sessions_intraday_? If it is, this table will be deleted after the process to create the ga_sessions_* tables. The process has likely done in the morning of your setting timezone, we often received the full table at 6 AM. I don't know why, but sometimes the intraday table still be there even the data in ga_sessions_ is already received, we have more than 50 days the intraday data still be there in the last 2 years.

From the doc, it is not SLA that this process is done at a specific time. Sometimes, we received the whole ga_sessions_ data in the afternoon or one time in the next day afternoon.

Comment: Thanks @KaBoom for your response, It's the (ga_realtime_sessions_*) not the (ga__sessions_intraday_*), I have seen new events get added in the early hours of the new day while a new ga_realtime_sessions_*  of that day was created